# Foundation 6 Drilldown Animation Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, zurb-foundation

I'm aiming to apply custom animation speeds to the Foundation 6 drilldown menu in Foundation 6 For Sites. I know that in `_settings.scss`, you a can alter the initial click animation through `$drilldown-transition`, however the animation parameters are ignored when going back a level in the drilldown.

I've checked `dist > assets > css > app.css` to see if some other parameter or some kind of hidden bit of CSS was controlling this, but it's evident to me that it's handled via JS beyond just adding / removing classes.

**TLDR;** I'm looking for insight on how to control the animation speed / style of the drilldown menu when going back a level vs going forward a level.

EXP: https://media.giphy.com/media/X8M8Hax10K9SslPN1v/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0):

The close-speed was due to the following lines, viewable in `dist > assets > css > app.css`

```
.drilldown .is-drilldown-submenu.is-active {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
            transform: translateX(-100%); 
    }

  .drilldown .is-drilldown-submenu.is-closing {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%); 
    }
```

The shift from `-100%` to `100%` is too extreme to really get the smooth feel you'd expect. Reducing `100%` to `5%` resolved the issue.

```
.mobile_nav > .grid-x > .cell > .is-drilldown .drilldown .is-drilldown-submenu.is-closing {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(5%);
          -ms-transform: translateX(5%);
              transform: translateX(5%);
    }
```